# Is Allah's name complete without diacritics?

Tags: allah

Can i write Allah's name simple without diactritics ? -

What are diacritics(Zer zabar pesh) called in Arabic/urdu?

```
Can any one name the one's used in Allah's name?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write names of Allah, without diacritics. Diacritics are mostly to help Non-Arabs to read Arabic texts.

---

Diacritics in Arabic:

Hamza - indicates glottal stop.

Tanwin - plays grammatical role.

Shadda - doubles consonant.

Wasla & Madda - Hamza related, look for Hamza in wikipedia.

Short Alif - Used instead of dropped Alif in writing.

Harakat or Tashkil - Vowel sound indicators.

- Fatha : /a/
- Kasra : /i/
- Damma : /u/
- Sukun : No vowel sound.

---

Word "Allah" contains of 4 letters: Alif+Lam+Lam+Ha. The diacritics in standard writing: Fatha on Alif, Shadda on second Lam, and Short Alif on Shadda, and Damma on Ha.

Comment: Here is wiki links for you: [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamza
  [2]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_language
  [3]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadda